# Does spark utilize the sorted order of hbase keys, when using hbase as data source

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, hbase

I store `time-series` data in `HBase`. The rowkey is composed from `user_id` and `timestamp`, like this:

```
{
    "userid1-1428364800" : {
        "columnFamily1" : {
            "val" : "1"
            }
        }
    }
    "userid1-1428364803" : {
        "columnFamily1" : {
            "val" : "2"
            }
        }
    }

    "userid2-1428364812" : {
        "columnFamily1" : {
            "val" : "abc"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now I need to perform per-user analysis. Here is the initialization of `hbase_rdd` (from [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/hbase_inputformat.py))

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="HBaseInputFormat")

conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host, "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": table}
keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"
valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"

hbase_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
        keyConverter=keyConv,
        valueConverter=valueConv,
        conf=conf)
```

The natural mapreduce-like way to process would be:

```
hbase_rdd
   .map(lambda row: (row[0].split('-')[0], (row[0].split('-')[1], row[1])))  # shift timestamp from key to value
   .groupByKey()
   .map(processUserData)  # process user's data
```

While executing first map (shift timestamp from key to value) it is crucial to know when the time-series data of the current user is finished and therefore groupByKey transformation could be started. Thus we do not need to map over all table and store all the temporary data. It is possible because hbase stores row-keys in a sorted order.

With hadoop streaming it could be done in such way:

```
import sys

current_user_data = []
last_userid = None
for line in sys.stdin:
    k, v = line.split('\t')
    userid, timestamp = k.split('-')
    if userid != last_userid and current_user_data:
        print processUserData(last_userid, current_user_data)
        last_userid = userid
        current_user_data = [(timestamp, v)]
    else:
        current_user_data.append((timestamp, v))
```

The question is: how to utilize the sorted order of hbase keys within Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with the guarantees you get with the way you're pulling data from HBase, but if I understand correctly, I can answer with just plain old Spark.

You've got some `RDD[X]`.  As far as Spark knows, the `X`s in that `RDD` are completely unordered.  But you have some outside knowledge, and you can guarantee that the data is in fact grouped by some field of `X` (and perhaps even sorted by another field).

In that case, you can use `mapPartitions` to do virtually the same thing you did with hadoop streaming.  That lets you iterate over all the records in one partition, so you can look for blocks of records w/ the same key.

```
val myRDD: RDD[X] = ...
val groupedData: RDD[Seq[X]] = myRdd.mapPartitions { itr =>
  var currentUserData = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[X]()
  var currentUser: X = null
  //itr is an iterator over *all* the records in one partition
  itr.flatMap { x => 
    if (currentUser != null && x.userId == currentUser.userId) {
      // same user as before -- add the data to our list
      currentUserData += x
      None
    } else {
      // its a new user -- return all the data for the old user, and make
      // another buffer for the new user
      val userDataGrouped = currentUserData
      currentUserData = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[X]()
      currentUserData += x
      currentUser = x
      Some(userDataGrouped)
    }
  }
}
// now groupedRDD has all the data for one user grouped together, and we didn't
// need to do an expensive shuffle.  Also, the above transformation is lazy, so
// we don't necessarily even store all that data in memory -- we could still
// do more filtering on the fly, eg:
val usersWithLotsOfData = groupedRDD.filter{ userData => userData.size > 10 }
```

I realize you wanted to use python -- sorry I figure I'm more likely to get the example correct if I write in Scala.  and I think the type annotations make the meaning more clear, but that it probably a Scala bias ... :).  In any case, hopefully you can understand what is going on and translate it.  (Don't worry too much about `flatMap` & `Some` & `None`, probably unimportant if you understand the idea ...)

Comment: Yeah, but the problem would be with the users that are distributed between two different partitions, right?

Comment: yes that is correct.  I was mostly just translating your hadoop-streaming example, but that seems like a red-herring.  I think your question is really: I have data stored in HBase with certain properties (eg., users grouped together) -- how do I get that data into an RDD, where I maintain those properties?  Or maybe, the data isn't already grouped in HBase, but you want HBase to do the grouping for you (rather than asking spark to do it)?  Not that I have the answer to either of those questions, but I think that clarification might help get you an answer.

Comment: also -- the data is getting split into partitions the same way it is in Hadoop, so if you expect TableInputFormat to already do what you want with Hadoop, then it will work w/ Spark as well.